# Sorting contents of a listbox

Tags: arrays, vb.net, listbox

I'm using the following code to add items to a listbox:

```
Dim i As Integer = 0
Dim temp As String

ListBox2.Items.Clear()
While i <= 9
    temp = Str(final_average(i)) + "        " + Str(i + 1) + "             " + Str(cals(i))
    ListBox2.Items.Add(temp)
    i = i + 1
End While
```

I want to sort this using the `average` or `final_average(i)`, but the following code doesn't seem to work:

```
Dim arr(ListBox2.Items.Count - 1) As Object

ListBox2.Items.CopyTo(arr, 0)
Array.Sort(arr)
ListBox2.Items.Clear()
ListBox2.Items.AddRange(arr)
```

How do I sort the contents of the listbox?

*(Note: This is not homework but part of a bigger project).*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the proper way to do it.

**A.** First create your list items class.

```
Public Class MyListItem
    Implements IComparable(Of MyListItem)

    Public FinalAverage As Integer
    Public Number As Integer
    Public Cals As Integer

    Public Sub New(ByVal finalAverage As Integer, ByVal number As Integer, ByVal cals As Integer)
        Me.FinalAverage = finalAverage
        Me.Number = number
        Me.Cals = cals
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        '' the way you want it to be shown in the listbox.
        Return String.Format("{0}        {1}             {2}", FinalAverage, Number, Cals)
    End Function

    Public Function CompareTo(ByVal other As MyListItem) As Integer Implements System.IComparable(Of MyListItem).CompareTo
        '' the way list items are compared for sorting... Return 0 for equal, -1 for smaller, +1 for bigger
        If Me.FinalAverage < other.FinalAverage Then Return -1
        If Me.FinalAverage > other.FinalAverage Then Return 1
        Return 0
    End Function
End Class
```

**B.** Now use this class to add items to your listbox.

```
    Dim listItems As New List(Of MyListItem)
    For i As Integer = 0 To 9
        listItems.Add(New MyListItem(final_average(i), i + 1, cals(i)))
    Next
    listItems.Sort()
    ListBox2.DataSource = listItems
```

And that's it! :)

Comment: You are making it complex. There is no need to make a new class. If simple way is solving the purpose, why to go for a complex one?

Comment: Umm.. Is it really complex? :)  You are relying on default string sort. The code above shows how to detach sorting from what is displayed in the ListBox. Means, the code will work even if the positions of final_average and cals is changed. Besides this, it is much more efficient than copying all the items to an array/collection, sorting them and adding them back to the ListBox. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it is complex! You are creating a new class, two new functions, a new Sub, declaring too many variables, there are implements and loops. It will consume more memory and which will make it less efficient and more prone to errors. Alright! It is okay if you find it better! :) Let the OP decide it!

Comment: I agree with pradeep here. This is a more elegant way to do it :)

Comment: Second method is much more elegant way of doing it. agree.thanks guys for taking time to help. Thanks to both Kashish and Pradeep.

Comment: Piling on, but I agree that I like this answer better. It keeps the display of the items separate from the sorting. The only (tiny!) thing I would change: Removing the `if` from the `CompareTo()` and simply returning the comparison of the `FinalAverage` directly. But that's just me! :)

Answer (score 1):

I have a rather simpler solution to your problem!

### Method 1

**1) Sort the items in `Listbox1`:**

We will do this by setting the `Sorted` property of `Listbox1` to `True`. It will keep your old list which was not sorted safely!

```
listBox1.Sorted = True
```

**2) Send the items to `Listbox2`:**

Copy all the items from `listbox1` to `listbox2` by saving it to an object collection. They will move in order, and hence, the second one is sorted from A-Z.

```
Dim objCollection As Object() = New Object(listBox1.Items.Count - 1)
listBox1.Items.CopyTo(objCollection, 0)
listBox2.Items.AddRange(objCollection)
```

**3) Place items in `Listbox1` in proper order:**

We have both the `listbox` with sorted items. Now, all we need to do is to place items in the previous order. As I said, your placement of items will be stored safely, we will retrieve it back by setting the `Sorted` property of `Listbox1` to `False`.

```
listBox1.Sorted = False
```

And, you will get a sorted `listbox2`!

### Method 2

Instead of sorting and then copying and then unsorting `listbox1`, you can first copy all items to `listbox2` and then sort `listbox2`. In this case, there will be no need of unsorting the first one again!

I hope it works perfectly!